# INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE is not defined

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am creating an App using `GCM` and when I tried to use the folowing line:

```
token = instanceID.getToken("32xxxxx", GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

I found that `GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE` is not available, please have a look at `image-1` below.

please let me know what i am missing and how to fix it.

**image-1**:

[image]

Comment: Try to use this dependency: **compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'**.

Comment: @huk i am currently using 4.3.23...would you please tell me what is the version number right after 4.3.23?because i used the version number you provided 8.3.0 and it caused some errors in the App

Comment: I don't know what errors you are getting after upgrading to 8.3.0 but you can check official docs [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Obtain a registration token](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) guide, I think you need to define your InstaceID like

```
@Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // ...
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
RegistrationIntentService.java

        // ...
    }
```

which looking at your code is nowhere to be found.

This is the InstanceID implementation in FCM from the [Firebase Cloud Messaging Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging):

```
  // Get token
  String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Comment: your beautiful picture says Google Cloud Messaging. Can you refer the docs you're following?

Answer (score 0):

The `GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE` just points out to a Constant String value `"GCM"` -- see [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging#INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE) (this if for old/GCM versions -- not entirely sure if this still works). For FCM, if you're unable to find the INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, you could just use `"FCM"`.

For the part where it's not available, it's possible that there are some libraries that you haven't imported yet.